# Automating Linux (Like AutoHotKey for windows)

Tags: software-recommendation, automation

What programs are available for Linux that can give a context sensitive automation like AutoHotKey for Windows.  a few example of things that I would like to do.

1. Replace `]d` with the current date, when typed.
2. Map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to <kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> when on a Chrome browser with Google+.  For quick posting.
3. Replace a string "mysig" with a signature when either Gmail is pulled up or when an evolution new mail window has the focus.

What options are there for this?  I would really like a program that is independent of all others so that I can have shortcuts and hot-strings map across all programs.  I've really gotten used to the date string and a few others that are very handy.

Comment: can I ask the obvious - why not install autohotkey for linux as per the question and answer? http://askubuntu.com/questions/6237/is-there-any-way-to-get-autohotkey-or-ironahk-working

Comment: @fossfreedom That answer suggests using AutoKey, not AutoHotKey, completely unrelated programs, but otherwise I agree...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`AutoKey` can do everything you're asking for. You can find it in the `Ubuntu Software Centre`.

Comment: Ooh! Looks like its python based as well! <3